# Why multiprocessing is slower than simple for loop?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I just learned about multiprocessing and tried to see how fast is it compared to simple for loop.
I use simple code to compare it,

```
import multiprocessing
from time import time as tt

def spawn(num,num2):
    print('Process {} {}'.format(num,num2))
#normal process/single core
st = tt()
for i in range (1000):
    spawn(i,i+1)
print('Total Running Time simple for loop:{}'.format((tt()-st)))

#multiprocessing
st2 = tt()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1000):
        p=multiprocessing.Process(target=spawn, args=(i,i+1))
        p.start()
print('Total Running Time multiprocessing:{}'.format((tt()-st2)))
```

The output that I got showed that multiprocessing is much slower than the simple for loop

```
Total Running Time simple for loop:0.09924721717834473
Total Running Time multiprocessing:40.157875299453735
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: to start 1000 processes need time. Note also you do not wait for the end of the processes so the time you measure is wrong. To multi-process is only relevant when the computation in each is long, and this is not the case here

Comment: Try adding a `sleep(0.1)` in your spawn function. multiprocesing has an over head that it needs to start each process individually. In this case the over head of starting will actually be longer than the function takes to run. Multiprocessing is normally used for tasks which take a long time to run one after the other so allows them to work in parallel. Try adding the 0.1 sleep to your function to make it take a bit more time and see which is faster then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the overhead for handling the processes. In this case the creation and deletion of the processes does not weigh up to the performance boost the code gets from running it parallel. If the executed code is more complex there will probably be a speedup.